# 'SUM(total)' of SQLIte does not work on android device but on browser

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am quite a new to ionic framework. I have been developing an app with SQLite. The app works fine on browser. But when I run on device it says

```
Cannot read property 'SUM(total)' of undefined
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
 $scope.items = [];
    $scope.grandTotal = 0;
    $scope.receiptnumber = 0;
    $scope.receiptnumber = $scope.receiptnumber + 1;
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.item = {};
    $scope.grandTotal = null;



    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        //EXPERIMENT CODE STARTS 
        var query2 = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE quantity!='' ";
        console.log(query2);
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query2, []).then(function (res) {

            if (res.rows.length > 0) {

                for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {

                    $scope.items.push({

                        itemname: res.rows.item(i).itemname,
                        price: res.rows.item(i).price,
                        quantity: res.rows.item(i).quantity,


                    });

                    // $scope.items = $scope.items;
                    // console.log($scope.items);
                    $scope.items = $scope.items;

                }
            } else {
                console.log("No results found");
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.error("error=>" + err);
        });

        //EXP CODE ENDS


        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();



        //GRAND TOTAL CALCULATION STARTS
        var query = "SELECT SUM(total) FROM items";

        console.log(query);
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function (res) {


            // $scope.grandTotal = res.rows[0]['SUM(total)'];
            console.log("SUM TOTAL TEST");
            console.log(res.rows);



        }, function (err) {
            console.error("error=>" + err);
        });



        //GRAND TOTAL CALCULATION ENDS            







        //Back button STARTS
        $scope.myGoBack = function () {

            $state.go("menu.sales");
            // window.history.back();

        };

        //BackButton ends

        //Charge button functionality STARTS===============================/////////////////////////

        $scope.charge = function () {

            $state.go('transactionsuccess');

            // INITIAL UPDATE OF ORDER NUMBER STARTS

            // var query5 = "UPDATE receipt SET ordernumber=" + "'" + $scope.receiptnumber + "'" + " WHERE quantity!='' OR quantity!='undefined' ";
            // console.log(query5);

            // $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query5, []).then(function (result) {

            //     $scope.items = [];
            //     $scope.grandTotal = 0;


            // }, function (err) {
            //     console.error(err);
            // });

            //ENDS            

        }


    });
```

What I am doing is rather than saving the SUM value into database I am directly fetched it from the program. Which is being done by this piece of code:

```
$scope.grandTotal = res.rows[0]['SUM(total)'];
```

Because I don't know any alternative to fetch the SUM(total) and save it in a variable so that it works both on browser and device... Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried to use alias?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html) says:

> The name of a result column is the value of the "AS" clause for that column, if there is an AS clause. If there is no AS clause then the name of the column is unspecified and may change from one release of SQLite to the next.

So you must use `SELECT sum(total) AS MyLittleSum ...` to get a predictable column name.